# Is there a way to use a thread across different class files in JavaFX?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, runnable

Okay, so I am not new at programming in Java, but I am new at using threads in my Java programs. I am in school and just finished the chapter on threads and Java networking. I was working on programming a client GUI that sends loan information( annual interest rate, number of years, and loan amount) to a server. The server has its own GUI and calculates the monthly payments and the total payment of the loan and sends it back to the client and be displayed to the user as well as updating the server GUI.

The book has this code as an example:

```
public class Server extends Application {
/** Variables */
private TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
private double rate;
private int year;
private double loan;

public void start(Stage serverStage)
{
    // Creating server GUI
    Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(textArea), 400, 200);
    serverStage.setTitle("Server");
    serverStage.setScene(scene);
    serverStage.show();

    new Thread(() ->{

        try
        {
            // create server socket
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
            textArea.appendText("Server started at " + new Date() + "\n");

            while(true)
            {
                // listen for a connection request
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = socket.getInetAddress();
                    textArea.appendText("Connected to " + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + " at " + new Date() + "\n");
                });


                // create and start a new thread for every connection
                new Thread(new HandleAClient(socket)).start();

            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
}

class HandleAClient implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket; // A connected socket
    private double rate;
    private int year;
    private double loan;

    /** costruct a thread */
    public HandleAClient(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    /** run a thread */
    public void run(){
        try
        {
            // create data input and output streams
            DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            // continuously serve the client
            while(true) {
                // read data from client

                rate = inputFromClient.readDouble();
                year = inputFromClient.readInt();
                loan = inputFromClient.readDouble();


                // calculate monthly payment of loan and total payment

                outputToClient.writeDouble(calculateMonthlyPayment(rate, year, loan));
                outputToClient.writeDouble(calculateTotalPayment(rate, year, loan));

                Platform.runLater( () -> {
                    textArea.appendText("The rate is : " + rate + "\n");
                    textArea.appendText("The number of years is: " + year + "\n");
                    textArea.appendText("Loan amount is: " + loan + "\n\n");});




            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// calculateMonthlyPayment method calculates the monthly payment of a loan given
// the required information

public double calculateMonthlyPayment(double interestRate, int years, double loanAmt)
{
    double monthlyRate;
    int termInMonths;
    double monthlyPayment;

    // Convert the interest rate to a decimal
    interestRate = interestRate / 100;

    // convert annual interest rate to monthly interest rate
    monthlyRate = interestRate / 12;

    // calculate the term in months which is years * 12
    termInMonths = years * 12;

    monthlyPayment = (loanAmt*monthlyRate) / (1-Math.pow(1+monthlyRate, -termInMonths));

    return monthlyPayment;
}



// method that calculates and returns the total payment of the loan
public double calculateTotalPayment(double rate, int year, double loan)
 {
    double totalPayment;
    double monthlyPay;

    monthlyPay = calculateMonthlyPayment(rate, year, loan);


    totalPayment = monthlyPay * 12 * year;

    return totalPayment;
  }

}
```

As you can see in the example code, they(the authors of the book) use a new Thread to be able to append the text of the server GUI. To be able to handle multiple clients however, a new thread is created inside of the while loop to handle each individual client.

I tried creating the HandleAClient class as a separate Java class instead of inserting it in the Server class but this resulted in the Server GUI not being updated with the Platform.runLater code

```
Platform.runLater( () -> {
                    textArea.appendText("The rate is : " + rate + "\n");
                    textArea.appendText("The number of years is: " + year + "\n");
                    textArea.appendText("Loan amount is: " + loan + "\n\n");});
```

So my question: Why is it that it works when the HandleAClient class is inside of the Server class and doesn't when the HandleAClient class is in a separate Java class file extending Server? I think it has to do something with the threads? What would I change to be able to have the HandleAClient class in its own Java class file ?

I am curious and trying to have a good understanding on how threads work. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
This is the standalone class that did not work for me. I extended the Server class and I made the TextArea field protected in the Server class.

```
class HandleAClient extends Server implements Runnable {

private Socket socket; // A connected socket
private double rate;
private int year;
private double loan;


public HandleAClient(Socket socket)
{
    this.socket = socket;
}

/** run a thread */
public void run(){
    try
    {
        // create data input and output streams
        DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        // continuously serve the client
        while(true) {
            // read data from client

            rate = inputFromClient.readDouble();
            year = inputFromClient.readInt();
            loan = inputFromClient.readDouble();


            // calculate monthly payment of loan and total payment

            outputToClient.writeDouble(calculateMonthlyPayment(rate, year, loan));
            outputToClient.writeDouble(calculateTotalPayment(rate, year, loan));

            Platform.runLater( () -> {
                textArea.appendText("The rate is : " + rate + "\n");
                textArea.appendText("The number of years is: " + year + "\n");
                textArea.appendText("Loan amount is: " + loan + "\n\n");});

        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The code in the Platform.runLater doesn't appear in the server GUI as it did when the class was inside of the Server class. I want to understand why this happens essentially.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The `HandleAClient` class should work fine as a standalone class, as long as it has access to all the fields of the `Server` class that it needs to access (really the only difference between an inner class and a top-level class is that the inner class has access to the fields of its surrounding class). When you implemented it as a top-level class, how did you give it access to the `textArea`? Can you post the full version of the standalone (top-level) `HandleAClient` class that didn't work?

Comment: Yes I updated my original post to include the class that didn't work. Basically I made the textArea field protected in the Server class and extended the Server class to the HandleAClient class.

Comment: The text area you are updating here is a different one to the one that you are displaying in the UI, though. You need to update the one belonging to the `Server` instance that is displaying the UI.

Comment: I don't understand. There is only one textArea field between the two classes

Comment: There is a `textArea` for each instance you create. (It makes no sense to me as to why you would have `HandleAClient` a subclass of `Server`: a `HandlerAClient` is not a `Server`, but that is sort of irrelevant.) When `Server` is instantiated, its instance has a `textField`. Each time you create a `HandleAClient` object, it has its own `textField`. (I thought you said you were experienced in Java? This is pretty basic stuff.)

Comment: BTW your question really has nothing at all to do with the fact that you are using threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your `HandleAClient` instances to update the text area that belongs to the `Server` object that creates them: the `textArea` belonging to that `Server` instance is the one that is displayed in the UI. With the setup you have, each `HandleAClient` instance has its own `textArea`, and each one updates its own `textArea`. None of those are ever displayed, of course.

It doesn't really make sense to me for `HandleAClient` to extend `Server`. What you need to do (whether you have that inheritance or not) is provide a way for `HandleAClient` to update the text area belonging to the `Server`. The simplest (but not necessarily best) way is just to pass that text area to the `HandleAClient` instances:

```
class HandleAClient implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket; // A connected socket
    private double rate;
    private int year;
    private double loan;

    private final TextArea textArea ;

    public HandleAClient(Socket socket, TextArea textArea)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.textArea = textArea ;
    }

    /** run a thread */
    public void run(){
        try
        {
            // create data input and output streams
            DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            // continuously serve the client
            while(true) {
                // read data from client

                rate = inputFromClient.readDouble();
                year = inputFromClient.readInt();
                loan = inputFromClient.readDouble();


                // calculate monthly payment of loan and total payment

                outputToClient.writeDouble(calculateMonthlyPayment(rate, year, loan));
                outputToClient.writeDouble(calculateTotalPayment(rate, year, loan));

                Platform.runLater( () -> {
                    textArea.appendText("The rate is : " + rate + "\n");
                    textArea.appendText("The number of years is: " + year + "\n");
                    textArea.appendText("Loan amount is: " + loan + "\n\n");});

            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And then of course in `Server` you modify it as

```
while(true)
{
    // listen for a connection request
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        InetAddress inetAddress = socket.getInetAddress();
        textArea.appendText("Connected to " + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + " at " + new Date() + "\n");
    });


    // create and start a new thread for every connection
    new Thread(new HandleAClient(socket, textArea)).start();

}
```

---

It feels a bit unnatural to let the `HandleAClient` class (which is responsible for communication) rely on having a reference to a `TextArea` (which is UI-specific). A more natural approach is as follows.

I would probably define a simple class to represent rate, year, and loan:

```
public class LoanData {

    private final double rate ;
    private final int year ;
    private final double loan ;

    public LoanData(double rate, int year, double loan) {
        this.rate = rate ;
        this.year = year ;
        this.loan = loan ;
    }

    public double getRate() {
        return rate ;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year ;
    }
    public double getLoan() {
        return loan ;
    }
}
```

And then give the `HandleAClient` class a `Consumer<LoanData>` for processing the loan data:

```
class HandleAClient implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket; // A connected socket

    private final Consumer<LoanData> dataProcessor ;

    public HandleAClient(Socket socket, Consumer<LoanData> dataProcessor)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.dataProcessor = dataProcessor ;
    }

    /** run a thread */
    public void run(){
        try
        {
            // create data input and output streams
            DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            // continuously serve the client
            while(true) {
                // read data from client

                double rate = inputFromClient.readDouble();
                double year = inputFromClient.readInt();
                double loan = inputFromClient.readDouble();


                // calculate monthly payment of loan and total payment

                outputToClient.writeDouble(calculateMonthlyPayment(rate, year, loan));
                outputToClient.writeDouble(calculateTotalPayment(rate, year, loan));

                dataProcessor.accept(new LoanData(rate, year, loan));

            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the server do

```
Consumer<LoanData> textAreaUpdater = 
    loanData -> Platform.runLater(() -> {
        textArea.appendText("The rate is : " + loanData.getRate() + "\n");
        textArea.appendText("The number of years is: " + loanData.getYear() + "\n");
        textArea.appendText("Loan amount is: " + loanData.getLoan() + "\n\n");
    });

new Thread(new HandleAClient(socket, textAreaUpdater)).start();
```

This keeps the UI data functionality properly secluded in the UI class.